# Adding a DEV in the URL of the website in IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, localhost

I added new website and in the Basic Settings in IIS i pointed Physical Path as "C:\inetpub\wwwroot". I put all my website code here and it works fine but the url is just the name of the server IIS is hosting. (Ex: http://xxx). I want to add DEV in the URL so i can differentiate between Dev and other websites (EX: http://xxx/DEV).

I tried adding folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DEV and access using URL http://xxx/DEV but it is throwing the below error.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 57:            </controls>
Line 58:        </pages>
Line 59:        <membership>
Line 60:            <providers>
Line 61:                <!--
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis You need to make an "application" as the error message said, not a simple folder called DEV.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off doing:

- add some entry to your hosts file mapping a name, like devsite1, to 127.0.0.1
- Change the bindings of the site so that it uses the new name
- visit the site's new name in the browser

In past jobs the office DNS has been configured so that `*.localhost.ourdomain.com` that points to 127.0.0.1, so anyone can just set up a website such as devchatroomv2.localhost.ourdomain.com in the IIS bindings and visit the url. Using a full domain can be helpful for things like session cookies if logins are handled by different sub domains in the same domain and is a reasonable replication of a live setup. I would hesitate to modify the path part of a url if your live site will use different paths; no sense setting yourself up for a headache when you can instead get experience of running a service across multiple different hostnames (failover/disaster recovery/redundancy/load balancing)

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to create Virtual application named DEV by following links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/

Some configuration is not allowed to be placed in the web.config of a folder by default. So create an sub-application to host your application would be the best way.